# Word 2013 : OLE in place editing not working?

Tags: c++, ms-word, ms-office, ole

I am struggling with getting in-place-editing to work with OLE objects in Word 2013 64bit.
I took Microsoft's own OLE sample [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

- Windows 7 64bit
- Office 2013 64bit
- OLE object is compiled in Visual Studio 2012, 64bit release
- another test with compilation in Visual Studio 2005 64bit produced the same result, so the MFC version is not likely to influence this behavior.

In place editing works with Powerpoint 2013, but not in Word 2013. In Word 2013, I get a "out-of-place" editing. In Word, I can add an Excel object and do in-place-editing with it.

The same sample project has in-place-editing (in both Powerpoint and Word) with the following setup :

- Windows 7, 64bit
- Visual Studio 2012 to compile, target Win32
- drop a Scribble document in Word 2010 32bit : in place editing works
- drop a Scribble document in Powerpoint 2010 32bit : in place editing works

Not working in Word 2013 32bit either with the following setup:

- Windows 7, 64bit
- Visual Studio 2012 to compile, target Win32
- drop a Scribble document in Word 2013 32bit : in place editing doesn't work
- drop a Scribble document in Powerpoint 2013 32bit : in place editing works

It's looking like Word 2013 is not capable of doing OLE in place editing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation revealed that this looks like a regression bug in Word 2013.
In-place editing does work in Word 2013, after you change the wrapping style of the OLE object to anything but "Inline with text".